# Android Maps overlaying a PNG image file

Tags: png, overlay, android-maps-v2

I am using Google Maps Android API v2 for creating a application which provides users with a custom map image and markers for place information. I would like to know if there is any option to overlay a PNG image file directly on top of Google Android maps. Something similar to the below example using Google Maps JavaScript API v3.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/maptype-image-overlay

Answer (score 1):

This example uses [TileOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/TileOverlay), but you may also try with [GroundOverlay](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/GroundOverlay), which has a simpler API and you can embeed your PNG directly without splitting it into tiles for all zoom levels. The drawback is you will see pixels on very high zoom levels.